# TFS Set Permission case of role

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I've installed and managed TFS 2017 serer

i want to ensure that the user on the virtual machines has only some permissions : launch build , view build console, push/pull code in branches

I've configured my server to set there persmission , but the user can override this settings when he click into security button

[image]

[image]

Thank you

[Update 1]

when i go to project security and check the group of my group "DevGroup" ; this last is a member of "Utilisateurs valides du projet" (this group have all permission) , when i try to remove this group as member of to "DevGroup" ;
this error message is showing :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Member of " of the users/group to see whether they have any admin permission. It's suggested adding the users/group in team project level, not collection level, and grant them the appropriate permission.

Comment: "Project Valid Users" contains all users and groups that have been added anywhere within the project. You cannot modify the membership of this group. What's the permission for group "Lecteurs"? Have you remove the group from team project collection level?

Comment: Can the users modify the security button after you removing them from team project collection level?

Comment: Have you remove them from team project **collection** level?